# AndroidSlidingUpPanel shows full screen when RecyclerView empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following problem. I am using:

AndroidSlidingUpPanel

which is exactly what I need.

I have a sliding in recyclerview from the bottom of the screen.
I set the view to wrap_content, so that if there is one item in the list, the view will only drag up to show one item. If there are more items, it will always only drag up to show the content. Great.
However I have one problem, when the list is empty, the view then drags up to take up the entire screen. In this case when the list is empty, I don't want it to drag at all.
Here is my xml of the main activity:

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="80dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/myplaces_recycler_view">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.berman.reuven.myplaces.MapsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/dragView">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/my_new_background_lighter"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="My Places"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitleList" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

            android:id="@+id/textViewNotesList" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myplaces_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />

</LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Here is the xml of the item in the recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/item_background"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/notesTextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```